# Sugar CRM: Add validation task before merge contacts

Tags: javascript, sugarcrm

Im trying to add a document number validation before two contacts will be merged into one, because in the merge process the user can modify that field and let an incorrect document number.

In SugarCRM documentation only refers to add validation task on create or record views but not on merge view.

Has someone already done something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've overwritten the *`merge-duplicates`* view (on custom/modules/Contacts/clients/base/views/merge-duplicates/merge-duplicates.js) and in the `triggerSave` event just after `this.clearValidationErrors` I added my validations:

```
this.clearValidationErrors (this.getFieldNames());

// My validations, I use this two variable to perform it:
newRecord = this.primaryRecord.attributes;
newRecordChanges = this.primaryRecord.changed;
```